# Como adicionar simulador IOS 12.2 no xCode 10.0?

Tags: ios, xcode, mac

Preciso emular o iphone com o IOS 12.2 mas meu xCode não tem essa opção. Vi que no xCode 10.2 vem com o IOS 12.2 mas o mac da empresa não deixa instalar porque precisa de um macOS mais recente.
Eu tentei a solução>
Baixar a imagem do 12.2 e jogar no caminho: contents >  developer > platforms > iphoneOS.platform > DeviceSupport
Reiniciei o xCode e tentei adicionar esse simulador com esse OS novo, mas não aparece a opção desse OS 12.2, tem alguma outra solução?

Comment: Depois de copiar a image do iOS 12.2 para o device support, você tentou criar um novo simulador indo em "Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Simulators -> +"? A opção de "OS version" não mostra o 12.2?

Comment: Desculpa perguntar, mas você já tentou pelo próprio xCode? Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Simulators -> + -> OS Version -> Download More?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa baixar o "Device support" referente a versão que esta querendo buildar seu app, [nesse link](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport) vc encontra todos os arquivos necessários.

Após baixar o arquivo vc precisa ir em:

`Applications⁩` ▸ `⁨Xcode.app⁩` ▸ `Show package Contents` ▸ ⁨`Contents⁩` ▸ ⁨`Developer⁩` ▸ ⁨`Platforms⁩` ▸ `⁨iPhoneOS.platform`⁩ ▸ ⁨`DeviceSupport⁩`

Joga o arquivo que vc baixou descompactado nessa pasta, fecha o Xcode e abre de novo

Pronto, agora vc consegue rodar seu app

Answer (score 1):

Estive pesquisando sobre isso e infelizmente não é possível instalar simuladores mais recentes em versões do xCode mais antigas. As versões do SDK necessárias para o simulador estão no próprio xCode, e instalar estes simuladores manualmente não funciona.

Abaixo a [release note do xCode 10.2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes):

> Xcode 10.2 includes SDKs for iOS 12.2, watchOS 5.2, macOS 10.14.4, and tvOS 12.2. Xcode 10.2 supports on-device debugging for iOS 8 and later, tvOS 9 and later, and watchOS 2 and later. Xcode 10.2 requires a Mac running macOS 10.14.3 or later.

Dito isso, é possível utilizar um device físico rodando iOS 12.2 para testar um aplicativo no xCode 10.2 seguindo a [solução do rodrigo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/410953/162667).